# Specific response from MsSQL DB

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, match, response

I am sending barcodes to a MsSQL DB using GET request via a Raspbery Pi using Python3

I have a second Pi which scans a barcode and send it to the same MsSQL DB. Now I need to get a message from the database if the barcodes have matched or not

Is it possible for a MsSQL engineer to input this "MATCH" or "NO-MATCH" in the response? SO that I can just use

```
requests.response(" ")
```

And get a "MATCH" or "NO-MATCH" message in the response?